# Python accessing web service protected by PKI/SSL

Tags: python, web-services, ssl, certificate, pki

I need to use Python to access data from a RESTful web service that requires certificate-based client authentication (PKI) over SSL/HTTPS. What is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion by stribika using `httplib.HTTPSConnection` should work for you provided that you do not need to verify the server's certificate. If you do want/need to verify the server, you'll need to look at a 3rd party module such as [pyOpenSSL](http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/) (which is a Python wrapper around a subset of the OpenSSL library).

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117004/
I did not try it so it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto). If you are a Twisted guy, [M2Crypto integrates with Twisted](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/M2Crypto/SSL/TwistedProtocolWrapper.py) so you can let Twisted handle the networking stuff and M2Crypto the SSL/verification/validation stuff.